# How find an object using Progress 4GL?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I need to find an object in a progress session... I don't know how to do... only with a sequential search, but it's very expensive(time consuming) if the number of objects is relative big.

Is there another way to do this?

```
define variable myObject As character no-undo.
define variable loop as Progress.Lang.Object no-undo.

assign myObject = "1234".

loop = Session:First-object.
do While valid-object(loop) :

  if (loop:tostring() = myObject) then Do:

    MESSAGE "Found!!!"
      VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
    leave.

  end.

  loop = loop:Next-sibling.

end.
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the end goal of this requirement?

Comment: What alternative search methods do you envision?  getObjectByValue() or something of that ilk?  (No, there is no such thing -- but if we knew better what you are trying to do and why then other ideas might suggest themselves.)

Comment: The OP's trying to implement garbage collection for the OO objects.